# Joining RTP multicast from the source

Tags: c++, windows, network-programming, rtp

This computer is taking SDI video as input and giving RTP stream as output. There is no problem joining this rtp multicast from another computer on the same network but if I run my software on the SDI to RTP machine, I can't get any packets.  There is no problem joining multicast but it acts like there are no packets.

We have 2 identical networks, I tried both, no success. I also tried some other software like VLC to see if they can get any packets and it seems they don't have any problem at all. I checked resource monitor and saw that these software are listening ports without giving a local ip address. I am always setting computers local ip address before joining any multicast stream to select the network ( there are 2 )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For jrtplib you need to set acceptOwnPackets before creating a session

```
RTPSessionParams rtp_sp;

rtp_sp.SetAcceptOwnPackets( TRUE );
```

Comment: multiple personality disorder? :)